# How to resize multiple images with gm in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a site on ExpressJS where people can upload images, and of course, I have to resize it to standart size. The problem is, I write a piece of code which work if user upload only one image, if upload two or three, NodeJS is crashing. I am sure, the problem is in my function call in for loop, I try some different methods, but that not resolved the problem. Hope, you can help me!

```
// ...

var resizeImage = function(image) {
  gm(image)
    .size(function(err, size) {
      if (!err) {
        if (size.width > size.height && size.width > 1024) {
          gm(image)
            .resize(1024, null)
            .write(image, function(err) { if (err) throw err; });
        } else if (size.width < size.height && size.height > 800) {
          gm(image)
            .resize(null, 800)
            .write(image, function(err) { if (err) throw err });
        } else if (size.width === size.height && size.height > 800) {
          gm(image)
            .resize(null, 800)
            .write(image, function(err) { if (err) throw err });
        }
      }
    });
};



if (rawImagesPath.length) {
  for (var j = 0; j < rawImagesPath.length; j++) {
    resizeImage(rawImagesPath[j]);
  }
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how to resolve this problem! Here is the code!

```
    var xy = 0;

    var resizeImage = function() {
        var thisImage = rawImagesPath[xy];


        gm(thisImage)
            .size(function(err, size) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);


                if (!size) {
                    xy = 2;
                } else if (size.width > size.height && size.width > 1024) {
                    gm(thisImage)
                        .resize(1024, null)
                        .write(thisImage, function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); });
                } else if (size.width < size.height && size.height > 800) {
                    gm(thisImage)
                        .resize(null, 800)
                        .write(thisImage, function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); });
                } else if (size.width === size.height && size.height > 800) {
                    gm(thisImage)
                        .resize(null, 800)
                        .write(thisImage, function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); });
                }


                if (xy == 2)
                    clearInterval(yz);
                else
                    xy++;
            });
    };


    var yz = setInterval(resizeImage, 1000);
```

Comment: You could use Async https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#parallel to speed up process.